# How do I stop VB6 Winsock from sending an end of stream byte?

Tags: vb6, tcp, end-of-line

How do I stop VB6 Winsock from sending an end of stream byte? It sends a 0 after each message, and it is messing with my code.

Comment: Can you just ignore the zero? If it sends one every time just ignore the last byte in the stream.

Comment: Something fishy here.  First Winsock does not support "messages" in TCP (you did say "stream"), second I have never seen any "end of stream" 0 bytes.  Sounds like a logic error in your code.

Comment: @BobRiemersma: You're absolutely right, if you post this as an answer I'd be glad to mark you. I allocated 1 byte more than I was using. I sent 23 instead of 22.

Comment: Thanks for the thought, but go ahead and give credit to the answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only bytes you receive are the ones that are sent.  TCP/IP will not add extra bytes.  Additionally, in TCP/IP, the "end of the stream" is not the same as the end of a message.  The stream never ends unless the connection is broken.

If you can post some code, we can get to the bottom on the problem.